# Sencha cmd 5 , No such command "app package"

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2.3, sencha-cmd5

I am following this tutorial : http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/apidocs/#!/guide/native_packaging-section-additional-resources

when I run the command

> sencha app package build android.json

I get this error :

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.2.270
[ERR] Unknown command: "package"
```

Anyone have an idea what's the problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well It turns out that `cmd 5` no longer supports Sencha Mobile Packager , they have shifted to `phonegap` and `cordova`.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287378-Mobile-Packager-Changes-in-Sencha-Cmd-5.0